# How to switch to windows authentication window in selenium webdriver using ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, authentication, selenium, webdriver

When I open the url, the system automatically pops the windows authentication with username and password fields and then I am unable to switch to the new popup window and enter credentials.

I tried uname:pwd<@domainname> format too and it still displays the windows authentication with blank username and pwd fields.

Can someone please provide me with a sample script that have worked for you? I am using selenium-webdriver and developing code in ruby.

Comment: Your `test_login` code is invalid. Also, the formatting needs to be improved. It'd help if you indented your source as that helps track where blocks are.

Comment: @Tin man, I am new to selenium/Ruby programming, So my formatting won't be perfect. Can you provide me with the code for switching to windows authentication screen and entering username and pwd? In my case when the authentication windows is open the the cursor is already on the username field, so I am assuming I don't have to switch the window instead just type in username and password, but I don't know how to enter those in windows authentication popup.

Comment: Your code in the example you gave *can* be formatted so it's more readable. I can't help you with the rest.

Comment: My code doesn't make sense, so removed it. Can someone please provide with sample script that worked for you guys?

Comment: If you are seeing the 'pop-up' authentication window then Webdriver will not be able to handle it - it is not part of the DOM. The username:password@url only works for basic-authentication. If the website you're trying to automate doesn't you basic-auth you may need to request from the developers than when from a test environment you can bypass that authorisation.